# Undefined variable: categories in blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I tried to create show function for main category but there is an error showing that variable categories is undefined. can help to solve it?

controller:

```
  public function show($id)
  {
    $categories = Categories::find($id);
    return view('Admin.categories.show',compact('maincategory'));
  }
```

blade:

```
{{ $categories->main_cate }}
```

Route:

```
 Route::get('/admin/show/{id?}', 
 ['uses'=>'AdminCategoriesController@show','as'=>'Admin.categories.show']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not pass the `$catgories` variable to the view. Do this:

```
return view('Admin.categories.show', compact('categories'));
```